# Arrays along two paths -- possible?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am trying to figure out how to create something like a bracelet where an object is arrayed around two different curves.

Example: Imagine a small gem that I want to be duplicated on the surface of a torus. I can create a gem, a small circle curve (the minor radius), and a larger circle (the major radius). I can create a curve modifier for the small circle and then an array modifier to get the gems to form a ring. But is there a way to array this assembly around a larger, perpendicular circle?

[image: Susanne bracelet start]

I can apply the first array and curve constraints before adding more curve and array modifiers, but this is destructive -- I want to still be able to edit the gem, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with adding a second array+curve modifier on top of the existing ones without applying? Apart from a potentially slow update and laggy interaction it should mostly work without issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redo the array and curves modifier combos:[image] Here is a blend file with the setup (you just need to change one monkey, everything will change automatically since its non-destructive):[image]

Comment: Instructive example! One detail surprised me -- the large circle was scaled up 5x. If I apply the scale to the circle (making it 1x), suzanne gets very distorted.

Comment: There are many things that you have to pay attention with the curves modifier: origin, scale, and axis. If you apply scale, location and rotation, the axis of the origin will shift to the current world axis, and ou might to update your working axis on the modifier. You migt also need to pay attention to other details! I totally recommend you to search for advanced tutorials on uses of the curve modifier! Good luck!

Comment: Select the curve, press Shift-S and select Cursor to Selected select the chain, press Shift-S and select Selection to Cursor

Then apply your curve modifier and the objects will follow the curve correctly.

The deformation is fixed scaling the object